# Netezza/DataStage SCD Type 2 issue

Tags: database-design, netezza, datastage, scd

I have seen an issue with SCD in Netezza/DataStage where slowly changing dimensions are being missed in UAT but being caught in Production.  The issue I am seeing is that; exactly the same rows flow into Production and where a change on one of the fields is caught, and the old record is expired and a new ‘active’ record is added, but in UAT the change on the same field is not caught.  Could someone please suggest some avenues of investigation i.e. could there be some setting in Production that is not set in UAT?  Is there any way so see what is happening with SCD in Production at the lowest level i.e. database logs etc?  We don’t really want to re-build SCD, but if someone can provide an approach that would allow us to get a much lower level view of what SCD is doing, that would be great.  We have analyzed the SCD set up in both environments and cannot see where the difference is.

EDIT: This issue where the SCD update are being missed seems to be happening on the same date column every time.  Do dates require any special SCD treatment?

Answer (score 0):

As a wild stab in the dark, start with these...

What are the regional setting on each appliance?

What is the date format for the appliance?

By appliance I mean Datastage server and not the Netezza Appliance.

For our dimensional data (well Data Vault Satellite Entities) in Netezza is being done as an after SQL statement.